# Algorithm optimisation to get first parent with specific kind of class

Tags: algorithm, recursion, swift, ios

I am writing an extension for `UIViewController` to search all the parents and return a specific parent which is a kind of specific class. here is my try :

```
extension UIViewController {

    var rootViewController : RootViewController? {
        var parentController: UIViewController? = parent
        while let currentParent = parentController {
            if (currentParent is RootViewController) {
                return (currentParent as? RootViewController)!
            }
            else if let parentOfParent = currentParent.parent, parentOfParent != currentParent {
                parentController = parentOfParent
            }
            else {
                parentController = nil
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

Is there a better approach to solve the issue, maybe a recursive way to handle that. And if it's better in term of performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't care much about performance here, since a view controller
hierarchy does not have hundreds of elements. But some things can
be simplified. First,

```
if (currentParent is RootViewController) {
    return (currentParent as? RootViewController)!
}
```

can be simplified to

```
if let rootVC = currentParent as? RootViewController {
    return rootVC
}
```

which also has the advantage that no forced unwrapping operator is
needed. Even if we know that it cannot fail here (because the type has
been checked in the if-statement) it is better to write the code
in a way that it becomes *obvious* that it cannot crash.

Next, the loop itself can be simplified:

```
var rootViewController: RootViewController? {
    var currentViewController = self
    while case let parentController? = currentViewController.parent,
        parentController != currentViewController {
        if let rootVC = parentController as? RootViewController {
            return rootVC
        }
        currentViewController = parentController
    }
    return nil
}
```

Here the "optional pattern"

```
    case let parentController? = currentViewController.parent
```

is used to check that there is a parent, and the constraint

```
    parentController != currentViewController
```

ensures that the parent is different from the current view controller.

But I don't think that a view controller can be its own parent.
If you don't have a special reason to consider this case, the code
can further be simplified using optional binding:

```
var rootViewController: RootViewController? {
    var currentViewController = self
    while let parentController = currentViewController.parent {
        if let rootVC = parentController as? RootViewController {
            return rootVC
        }
        currentViewController = parentController
    }
    return nil
}
```

Another suggestion is to make the method generic, so that it can 
be used to find a parent view controller of any given class:

```
func parent<T : UIViewController>(ofType: T.Type) -> T? {
    var currentViewController = self
    while let parentController = currentViewController.parent {
        if let parent = parentController as? T {
            return parent
        }
        currentViewController = parentController
    }
    return nil
}
```

Finally: You can replace the loop by recursion, using the
`flatMap` method of `Optional` and the nil-coalescing operator `??`:

```
func parent<T : UIViewController>(ofClass: T.Type) -> T? {
    return parent.flatMap { ($0 as? T) ?? $0.parent(ofClass: T.self) }
}
```

Here `parent.flatMap { ... }` returns `nil` if `parent == nil`, 
this terminates the recursion eventually. Otherwise `$0` is the
(unwrapped) parent. If the conditional cast `$0 as? T` succeeds
then this will be the return value. Otherwise the method is called
recursively on the parent view controller.

I doubt that this will be faster, and it is more difficult to read
and to debug. So it's up to you which approach you prefer.

Comment: Really great inputs

Comment: @iOSGeek: You are welcome!